# Using Google Chrome in Selenium VBA (Installation Steps)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am having problems even setting up Selenium for VBA. I have been reading online on what to do, download the selenium (https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) add extension and etc. However, I am still struggling to get it to work.

Even writing a simple code like the following which I have found online:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.google.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementById("lst-ib").SendKeys "Selenium basic GitHub"
         .FindElementsByTag("form")(1).FindElementByCss("input[value='Google Search']").Click
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Gives me an Automation error.

I would like to use google chrome in the same way as internet explorer.
I would appreciate any help with setting up selenium , and I know my question can be seen as silly.

Comment: Did you Check the Reference `Selenium Type Library` ? If not select the Reference in Tools>References

Comment: I did add the reference Selenium Type Library but for some reason it still gives me the automation error

Comment: Which line shows the error ?

Comment: Set d = New ChromeDriver

And the automation error that it gives me is :

Run time error : '-2146232576

Comment: That usually happens because of the Reference. Not sure what it is in your case.

Comment: I am confused as well as this is what it says everywhere I read, Unless somehow excel does not have access to this extension even though I have added it. Not sure if I need to download this extension from somewhere else as well or If i need to set it up somehow to use google chrome

Comment: Do you have the right chromedriver.exe for your version of chrome and is that driver in the selenium folder?

Comment: I will be honest and not really sure how to check compatability with the chrome driver versions or where to check them. The chrome I have installed is Version 75.0.3770.142. How to check what driver do I have? What exactly should I add to the selenium folder. I would expect to have to put something in the following folder C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic. I might sound silly but I appreciate any help and again thanks for the quick responses

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/   then if windows you want chromedriver_win32.zip  . Unzip and put the chromedriver.exe in the selenium folder (Replace the existing one if there is already one.

Comment: so I did that and put it into the folder. Not sure if it is a problem as the driver end on 140 and my google chrome ends on 142. Again I do get the same automation error. Also when I click on the chrome driver I get the following message : Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, go to control panel and uninstall previous installation of selenium and then follow the steps
1- Download the latest version of chrome and make sure of the version of Chrome from Help >> About Google Chrome. You would see something like that `Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (32-bit)`

2- Download the latest version from the [LINK](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/download/v2.0.9.0/SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0.exe)

3- Download the chromedriver from the follwoing [LINK](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
Make sure of the version that suits your chrome version
As for the Google Chrome version I posted the most suitable version of chromedriver is `ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140`

4. Now setup SeleniumBasic >> After setup unzip the chromedriver file `chromedriver_win32.zip` and copy the chromedriver.exe to the path of selenium
   Here's two possibilties: First >> `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic`
   Second >> `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic`
   Copy the chromedriver.exe to the SeleniumBasic path
5. Open new blank excel file >> Press Alt + F11 (Visual Basic Editor) >> Tools >> References >> Selenium Type Library
6. Insert new module and paste the following code to test

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim bot         As New WebDriver
    
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
    bot.Get "/"
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: Followed the steps, still continues to give the exact same error, Tomorrow I will try to find a different computer and try on it to see if it gives a different result.

Comment: @Wolf Kolev Which windows version do you use (32 Bit or 64 Bit) ..? May be there are specific firewall or antivirus that prevents SeleniumBasic...

Comment: I am using the 64 bit and I am wondering whether that chrome drive is not working as it says 32 bit on it. I will check my firewall setting as well to double check if something is stopping selenium from working.

Comment: No problem. I am using Windows 64Bit and Chrome 64 Bit / Chrome 32 Bit and both works fine with chromedriver.exe (which is 32Bit) ..

Comment: I am out of ideas, not sure why it is not working, I even turned firewall off and still does not work

Comment: YasserKhalil, you are the king of selenium, Reinstalled my net framework and it is working now, Huge thanks for the help, for the quick response and the fact that for the past week you kept checking on here and help me out, huge huge thanks

Comment: Now just left to learn how to navigate with selenium in the same way as I do in internet explorer

Comment: @Wolf Kolev You are so welcome. Glad I can offer some help. Hope this will help the other members too. Regards

Comment: You are a legend, works, thank you very much for this answer, Yasser!

Comment: @YasserKhalil can you maybe update your answer with what turned out to be the solution in the end?  I have the same issue as WolfKolev and I am not sure how to get from there - was it an issue with the Net Framework?

Comment: @Eleshar Try installing NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Install 3.5 too. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I got 3.5 as well but I think you are right about the problem being in the framework. I have apparently an issue with the NET framework. Most of the time, my Excel crashes when opening a file with PowerQuery. It crashes on "Loading .Net Framework". When I do manage to open such a file, I succeed in running the function too.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded chrome.exe to one version lower downloads (off the selenium chrome webdriver site) in Users/?/AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic directory and it worked.  ..running windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Check your chromedriver version from the command line -

PS C:\Users\david\appdata\Local\SeleniumBasic> .\chromeDriver -v
ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.70 (e52f33f30b91b4ddfad...

Download chromedriver version from here -

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

This code works on Windows 11 with Excel 365 VBA -

```
Sub sbChromeDriver() 
    Dim bt As New Selenium.ChromeDriver 
    bt.Start 
    bt.Get "https://www.google.com" 
    sbDelay (200000) 
End Sub

Sub sbDelay(delay As Long) 
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To delay
        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub
```