# Excel VBA to send text message to Whatsapp

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp, sendkeys

I have designed a code that sends a message from excel to WhatsApp to list of contacts, it works fine for single contact but when , more than one contact is added it doesn't move to that contacts instead paste other contact names & messages in the message box of the first contact. Here is the excel view, when I press the button the output which is Whatsapp web page doest work as desired as seen in picture.

[image]

I know there is some small bug but any support for resolution of this issue will be highly appreciated. Here is the code

```
Sub Test()

    Dim text As String
    Dim contact As String
    text = Range("C2").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=" https://web.whatsapp.com/"
    If MsgBox("Is WhatsApp Loaded?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Press No To Cancel", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "WhatsApp") = vbYes Then
        Fazer (100)
        startrow = 2
        startcol = 2
        Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, 1) = ""
            contact = Cells(startrow, 1)
            text1 = Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, startcol).Value
            Fazer (3000)
                Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys(contact, True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys("~", True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys(text1, True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys("~", True)
            Fazer (1000)
            startrow = startrow + 1
        Loop
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Function Fazer(ByVal Acao As Double)
    Application.Wait (Now() + Acao / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug as code looks good.

Comment: Yes but i can't figure it out any solution would be great

Comment: Have a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371366/)

Comment: @YasserKhalil yes I did research checked the code its same to this code but both are giving the same issue. After the first contact, it never moves out of that message box

Comment: Not the same at all. The solution on the link uses selenium in VBA.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Oh you mean that one but that one is for the picture I suppose, It would be great If we can have text option in that in column C and the picture will be optional. Thanks, I am new to this vba world not that expert, if you can edit it would be great.

Comment: You have to study the code first. And you will find it easy to add a text message.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I saw that but it seems altogether unfamiliar commands to me if you can assist with modification it would be a great favor as I am from marketing field design small vba when needed for the project. thanks dear

Comment: I don't mind but you have to make sure the code is working first for you as for attaching the picture or not.

Comment: Yes dear, I need for text. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in the code, the way in which WhatsApp Web works is just differently:

After sending your message in Whatsapp, it needs **two** Tab keystrokes to get to the field to search for contacts (the first tab will hover over the message you've just sent). *This applies for every iteration of your program after the first iteration.*

If you send no message or just opened WhatsApp Web (which you probably tested) it will need only **one** Tab keystroke. *This applies for the first iteration of your loop only but is currently included for every iteration.*

The easiest way to change this in your script is to add another line in the loop after sending the text to simulate this second necessary keystroke.

```
Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, 1) = ""
    contact = Cells(startrow, 1)
    text1 = Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, startcol).Value
    Fazer (3000)
        Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
    Fazer (1000)
        Call SendKeys(contact, True)
    Fazer (1000)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
    Fazer (1000)
        Call SendKeys(text1, True)
    Fazer (1000)
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
    Fazer (1000)
    startrow = startrow + 1
    Fazer (1000)
       Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True) 'Simulate the 2nd keystroke
Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the WhatsApp API and avoid open the wpp web (In  ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=" [https://web.whatsapp.com/"](https://web.whatsapp.com/%22)), a lot of "sendkeys" and "wait" methods.

Download:

https://www.whatsapp.com/download

Use the InternetExplorer and API with your phone "loaded", the link of the phonenumber should not have special characters (Check documentation)

See this simple example:

```
Sub wpp()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create object IE
    IE.navigate "whatsapp://send?phone=5511912341234&text=something" 'Send message "something" to this phone (Brazil)
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) 'ok just one wait and sendkeys :v
    SendKeys "~"
    'IE.Quit 'The navigate already kills the IE
    Set IE = Nothing 'Clear the object
End Sub
```

Comment: I used something similar, but to make it work, I had to change SendKeys "~" to SendKeys "{ENTER}". 
OBS: A command useful in formatting the message is SendKeys "+{ENTER}", which is the command of SHIFT+ENTER, adding a linebreak to the message.

Answer (score 0):

By making some changes to the Excel address book template that I created earlier, I created links to web.whatsapp.com for mobile phone numbers - also the mobile numbers are controlled by the macro - .  If the number is valid  (with the international code at the beginning) and the user has the WhatsApp application installed on their phone, you can send a message even if the number is not stored on your smart phone.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFQ8Te7U6ys

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://wa.me/" & ActiveCell.Value & "?text=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) 'ok just one wait and sendkeys :v
SendKeys "~"
```

[Review template](https://eksi30.com/send-whatsapp-message-from-excel-address-book/)