# Can MSXML2.XMLHTTP be used with Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using the following Excel VBA macro to bring back data from a website.  It worked fine until a few days ago when the website stopped supporting IE. Of course the macro just fails now as there is no data on the webpage to bring back to Excel, just a message saying, "Your browser, Internet Explorer, is no longer supported."  Is there a way to have the "Get method" (MSXML2.XMLHTTP) use Chrome instead of IE to interact with the website?  BTW, my default browser is already set to "Chrome".

```
Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument        ' note: reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library must be set

Sub KS()    
' Define product url
    KS_url = "https://www.kingsoopers.com/p/r-w-knudsen-just-blueberry-juice/0007468210784"
    
' Collect data
        Set html_doc = New HTMLDocument
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        xml_obj.Open "GET", KS_url, False
        xml_obj.send
        html_doc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
        Set xml_obj = Nothing
  
        KS_product = html_doc.getElementsByClassName("ProductDetails-header")(0).innerText
        KS_price = "$" & html_doc.getElementsByClassName("kds-Price kds-Price--alternate mb-8")(1).Value

      do Stuff

End Sub
```

Comment: [This might be your best bet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps/57224810).

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, it just so time consuming to actually open the webpage.  I'd prefer to stick with the faster "GET" method if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The check for this is a basic server check on user agent. Tell it what it wants to "hear" by passing a supported browser in the UA header...(or technically, in this case, just saying the equivalent of: "Hi, I am not Internet Explorer".)

It can be as simple as `xml.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Chrome"`. I said basic because you could even pass `xml.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "I am a unicorn"`, so it is likely an exclusion based list on the server for Internet Explorer.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub KS()
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://www.kingsoopers.com/p/r-w-knudsen-just-blueberry-juice/0007468210784"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xml As Object
    
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
       
    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    xml.send
    html.body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

    Debug.Print html.getElementsByClassName("ProductDetails-header")(0).innerText
    Debug.Print "$" & html.getElementsByClassName("kds-Price kds-Price--alternate mb-8")(1).Value

    Stop

End Sub
```

Compare that with adding no UA or adding `xml.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "MSIE"`.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, clear and complete, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Study the article here by *Daniel Pineault* and this paragraph:

[Feature Browser Emulation](https://www.devhut.net/2019/10/18/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-access-webbrowser-control/)

Also note my comment dated 2020-09-13.