VBA API call getting timeout - NEED ERROR HANDLING
Updated question - How can I capture ERROR on the SEND during the HTTP call below. I tried On Error , but no luck. Need some help.
I ran UPS API on Windows 2012R2 just fine and now I am getting a The Operation timed out on getting the TOKEN and/or at a certain number of calls of the API. Sometimes it runs sometimes it stops. I  run this from the scheduler configured for Windows Server 2019.
The error occurs on the SEND part, I can go back to the beginning of the WITH line and it will continue.
With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://onlinetools.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/".....", False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + strClientToken
    .setRequestHeader "test", "string"
    .setRequestHeader "trans", "testing"
    On Error Resume Next
    .send
    On Error GoTo 0
    If .status = 200 Then
        'resume
    Else
        GoTo CheckConnection
    End If

Tried running as Windows 2008R2 from task scheduler. I try to lock the screen and schedule the task. Anyone have any suggestions? I don't think I am hitting any max API calls per second or per hour. Used to work on 2012R2 server.

Or, getting timeout at .send, the ON ERROR GOTO is not working, how can I loop back when I get the timeout error. I don't know, maybe I need to use XMLHTTP.OnTimeOut = OnTimeOutMessage ?

A timeout response is not an error, it is a valid response.   Sounds more like an issue with the underlying browser on the server.   May want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911516/can-msxml2-xmlhttp-be-used-with-chrome
