# Using Excel VBA Macro to capture

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take a screenshot from list (about 1.045 address) of web address that I have on excel, then save that screenshot to specific folder with specific name. Can anyone help me with this issue? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried anything, just copied some module from another post, not working. I have zero experience on VBA/Macro, just want to make my work easier by using it.

Comment: Then your best bet is to start by recording a macro of you doing it manually, as learn from what it gives you. Maybe break it into pieces first.

Comment: A pragmatic approach. Use this command line tool. You can write a batch file that processes your list if you have all needed data like urls and wanted file names. You can use Excel as an auxiliary tool to "copy the contents of the batch file together": https://wkhtmltopdf.org Look here for programing batch files: http://www.trytoprogram.com/batch-file A solution in Excel only can be done with SeleniumBasic and the PhantomJS WebDriver. Look here on YasserKhalils answer to install SeleniumBasic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps

Comment: But note that there are websites that resist such action. You may not get the screenshot you expect. So first check whether the effort of programming a complete solution is worth it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.