# Opening Chrome from excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I am trying to figure out a way to navigate to Chrome in Vba

This works but i am unsur why I needs to be declared as a variable.

Additionally, if the cell I is refrencing is empty then it will not open it is there and way to open and navigate to a page without having it refrence the workbook

```
Sub multiplechrome()

Dim WebUrl As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
    WebUrl = "http://" & Cells(i, 1).Value & """"
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & WebUrl)

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `i` is the row number.

Comment: Can't you install software on the machine? The only way that I know to navigate in Chrome is by using Selenium, which is available for [Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps). If you don't have selenium you can only open webpages with VBA, and that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `WebUrl` to a default value.

Then if the cell is (not null and is not empty and is not blank) then you re-set `weburl` to the cell value.

Not tested, but try something like:

```
WebUrl = "chrome://newtab"
if isNull(Cells(i,1).Value) <> true AND isEmpty(Cells(i,1).Value) <> true AND Cells(i,1).Value <> "" then
WebUrl = "http://" & Cells(i, 1).Value & """"
end if
```

The obvious next bug is assuming the value is a valid url.