# VBA Error message - Runtime error '33' Selinium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am following along this video and get to the exact code he is at at 7:02 and get an error message when executing (https://youtu.be/y7yWL0oCB3k?t=422). I have Selenium library activated in my references:

```
Option Explicit

Private ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub ScrapeWiseOwlVideos()

    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://www.twittervid.com"
    
    ch.FindElementByName("url").SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Select


End Sub
```

Google chrome appears for a second but then instantly closes and I;m met with this error message:

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve please?

I have tried updating my chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. I downloaded the latest one and put it in my excel 16 folder but still the issue remains.
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: It crashed Chrome because you are sending Keys to an Element and it does not support it Instead of sending keys, edit the Element .value to "abc"

Comment: Also, depending on the version of the Selenium Driver you may be using an old method. It used to be FindElementByName and now is `findElement(By.name("elementName"))`

Comment: Thanks but using the (by.name option above it mentioned that by was not defined

Comment: The `findElement(By.name("elementName"))` syntax is Python.

Comment: My chromedriver.exe is in `C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic`

Comment: Check your  chromedriver version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps/77343812#77343812)