# Selenium Chromedriver - SessionNotCreatedError when setting profile

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a vba script that opens a locally hosted web page in app mode, and I need chrome to use the default profile.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I set the profile I get an error. Interestingly, the chrome window opens, with the correct profile set, without issue but selenium obviously can no longer see the chrome window open and assumes it's crashed.

Without setting the user Chromedriver works perfectly and interacts with my code as intended.

Chrome version 121.0.6167.86

Chromedriver version 121.0.6167.85

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
Sub pageopen()
     Dim chDrv As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
     Dim userDataDir As String
     userDataDir = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Google\Chrome\User Data\"

     chDrv.AddArgument ("--app=http://test-server/V4/home.html")

     chDrv.SetProfile userDataDir, True                 ' using this line gives the error

                                                        ' so I came up with this alternative but
     chDrv.AddArgument ("user-data-dir=" & userDataDir) ' using this line (even on it's own) gives the error
     chDrv.AddArgument ("profile-directory=Default")    ' using this line on it's own doesn't set the profile

     chDrv.Start

     ' Wait for the button click
     WaitForButtonClick chDrv

     'Quit ChromeDriver
     chDrv.Quit
End sub
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

It reads:

> Run-time error '33':  SessionNotCreatedError session not created:
> Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from
> chrome location C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (Driver info:
> chromedriver=121.0.6167.85

I fear I'm doing something stupid. I've read through several other posts about this issue but non seem to be caused by setting the user data directory and no answers there helped so I assume this is a separate issue. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The chromedriver version in the error message does not match the text you have entered in the question. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps/77343812#77343812) answer to make sure your Chrome and chromedriver versions are the same.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I copied the text from the same error I got before updating my chrome and chromedriver. The versions as mentioned in the top of the post are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because Your Chrome Browser's version is 121.0.6167.86 whereas your Chromedriver's version is 121.0.6167.85

Since 121.0.6167.86 is recently launched, its driver will take some time to come. Hence downgrade your browser to 121.0.6167.85 and issue will be resolved.

Comment: I tried downgrading my chrome and I still get the same error unfortunately. I should mention that without setting the user Chromedriver works perfectly and interacts with my code as intended.