Object not set error when trying to change inner Text in website
I'm trying to do a simple macro with a site that formats/beautifies code,
1- Insert a text in input box to the left
2- Click "Beautify" button
3- Copy the result of output box to the right
This is my current code but I'm getting run time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set for line inputBox.innerText = ...
Sub Test()
Dim url As String
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim inputBox As Object, outputBox As Object
Dim myBtn As Object

    url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_ruby_formatter.htm"

    oHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    oHttp.send
    
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText

    'Inserting code to beautify
    Set inputBox = html.getElementsByClassName("ace_content")(1)
    inputBox.innerText = "if" & vbCr & "sometext" & vbCr & "elsif" & vbCr & "other text" & vbCr & "else" & vbCr & "last text" & vbCr & "end" & vbCr
    
    'Click button to beautify
    Set myBtn = html.getElementsByClassName("l-btn-text")(7)
    myBtn.Click

    'Get text of beautified code
    Set outputBox = html.getElementsByClassName("ace_content")(0)
    Debug.Print outputBox.innerText
    
End Sub


Your plan does not work for various reasons. The main reason, however, is that xhr cannot process dynamic pages. This means that you can only load a static document from a web server. However, this has no functionality because JS is not executed. It is therefore not possible to trigger something by clicking a button.

What method do you suggest to do this with VBA macro?

You need browser automation. Since IE is outdated, this can be done in VBA with Seleniumbasic. In addition to Seleniumbasic, the latest WebDriver must also be installed. There are some for Chrome and Edge, for example. Have a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps#57224810

You declare it via
Dim inputBox As Object

and later on you try to use it via
    Set inputBox = html.getElementsByClassName("ace_content")(1)
    inputBox.innerText = "if" & vbCr & "sometext" & vbCr & "elsif" & vbCr & "other text" & vbCr & "else" & vbCr & "last text" & vbCr & "end" & vbCr

The element should exist:

The error that is being thrown claims that your variable is not specified correctly. You will need to run a debugger and double-check it for yourself.

Yes, I'm running the debugger, but I'm not finding the way to fix it.

@RasecMalkic what do you see as the value of inputBox?

I was seeing nothing but now I change to the way you show document.querySelectorAll(".ace_content") and it has the html object elements inside, but the error when trying to change inner text in next line is the same
